# How can I turn on split screen in GRID 2?

Tags: grid-2

I just bought that game from [origin](https://www.origin.com/pol/en-us/game-library/ogd/OFB-EAST:109549424/friends-who-play)

and I would like to play split screen like this:

but I cannot because there is no "events" option in my game.

I installed game on windows using macbook pro retina 2015 and connected 2 xbox 360 pads. However it seems that only one of them works. Why?

[image]
[image]

After **world series racing** there is no oprion for **events**. Why?

Answer (score 2):

These instructions are for GRID 2 Reloaded, but since that is only a few new circuits it should work as well.

> From the Main Menu, select **World Series Racing**.
>
> Select **Events**.
>
> Select **Splitscreen**.
>
> A dialog will appear prompting Player 2 to press the Start button. Player 2 must press a button on their input device to continue.
>
> The Splitscreen menu will appear. Select Custom Event.
>
> The game options screen will appear. From here, you can customize the game settings. When you are happy with your settings, select Done.
>
> Select Go to Race.
>
> The car selection screen will appear. Select a car.
>
> The car selection screen will reappear. Player 2 must select a car.
>
> The game will begin once Player 2 has selected a car.

[Source.](https://support.feralinteractive.com/en/mac-linux-games/grid2reloaded/faqs/multiplayer_splitscreen/)

Comment: what does it mean: `reloaded`? Do I have reloaded edition or not?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_2), the "Reloaded" is the Mac version of the game.

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought it had been re-released in PC as well. Anyhow, the menus should be identical anyhow.

Comment: but it seems that they are not identical:(

Comment: @CyberClaw So is it possible to turn it on with my version of the game? I realised also that only one controller interacts with the game, not both. How to make sure that both are connected?

Comment: You should be able to, but I'm not so sure anymore. Are you using a 360 controller? If they are with leds lit up, they should be connected. Test the controllers in windows control panel to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this for the first time for my kids. You need to have done the intro race and the speedway to get the 'intro elements' done - then Splitscreen is an option in the events.